# Suggestions for optimizing a fractal visualization method

Tags: optimization, fractals, mandelbrot

I've written up a variation on Melinda Green's Buddhabrot method for visualizing the Mandelbrot set. Here it is:

http://pastebin.com/RH6dD77F

To create an animation I rendered hundreds of the individual images with slight variations. The variation is a transformation of the coefficients of the generating function as if they were an abstract vector in a space of coefficients. All of that produced incredible structures in the video...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2uMAvL_5Fo

The problem? As you can tell, the quality on each image is rather low because it takes forever using the method I came up with (the copies I have on my computer are a little better quality, but still look like old reel-to-reel movies). I'm hoping to find a few methods for increasing quality or lowering output time.

Thanks for any suggestions. I would really like to produce more detailed versions of these. Obviously there is much more structure in the graininess of these images.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like boxcounting, http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/fraclac/FLHelp/BoxCounting.htm. If buddhabrot is some sort mandelbrot you can skip some empty boxes. You can use a kd-tree like in packing lightmaps to subdivide the surface.